# Обработка русских символов

Tags: c++

Есть заполненный словами `vector<string>`. Нужно узнать количество слов, которые начинаются на русские буквы.

Для анг. я сравнил `(*it)[0]` с англ. алфавитом, где `*it` есть `vector<string>::iterator it`.

А вот с русским у меня происходит вылет программы. Вот код:

```
int count = 0;
for(vector<string>::iterator it = arr.begin();it != arr.end();++it) {
    char c = (*it).c_str()[0];
    if (!(!isalpha(c) || c == 'a' || c == 'o' || c == 'i' || c == 'e' || c == 'u')count++;
}
```

Comment: забыл сказать то, что vector формируется с файла

Comment: @huxi вы лучше приведите код

Comment: @DreamChild если точнее сказать, то вылет происходит именно тогда, когда в файле появляются русские символы.  А с файла читает обычно, через потоки.

Comment: Какая кодировка русского?

Comment: @avp файл в кодировке cp1251.

Comment: @huxi, в приведенном фрагменте кода я причин для падения не вижу.

Вы нигде в других частях программы символ с русской буквой (все коды русских букв отрицательные числа) в качестве индекса не используете?

Comment: Дебаггер - мой лучший друг...

Comment: Ну, падение может быть при обращении к нулевому символу, если строка пустая.

Answer (score 2):

Вылет программы происходит потому, что в функции типа `isalpha` можно передать только символы из диапазона от 0 до 255 или константу EOF.

Русские буквы имеют коды больше 128 (в любой кодировке), и всё было бы хорошо, но по умолчанию `char c` - это `signed char c`, по этому для русской буквы мы получаем отрицательное число, и программа падает.

Замените `char c` на `unsigned char c`, или сделайте явное преобразование в `unsigned char` при вызове `isalpha`:

```
isalpha((unsigned char)c)
```